# AppleScript "with icon stop" for display dialog not working on MacOS 10.12

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-sierra

On MacOS 10.5, this osascript command works as expected, displaying a dialog box with a red stop sign:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to activate' 
          -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Picking a folder failed, exiting." with title "Start Up Error" buttons "Ok" with icon stop default button "Ok"' 
          -e 'tell app "System Events" to quit'
```

One MacOS 10.12, however, this command fails with the following cryptic error message:

```
427:433: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found class name. (-2741)
```

I've found that changing the icon "stop" above to "note" works on 10.12, displaying a dialog box without error, for example:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to activate' 
          -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Picking a folder failed, exiting." with title "Start Up Error" buttons "Ok" with icon note default button "Ok"' 
          -e 'tell app "System Events" to quit'
```

Can anyone else reproduce this issue?  Is there a way to fix it other than avoiding the stop icon?  I'm guessing it's a bug in AppleScript, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Lose the activate and quit lines, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you wish to target any AppleScriptable app which exhibits such a terminology conflict, it's also usually possible to first assign the conflicting term to a variable in an outer scope, and then within the `tell` scope use that variable instead.

For instance, in the case of the `System Events` app's conflict with the `stop` term (from `StandardAdditions.osax`), you could do the following:

```
osascript -e 'set kStopIcon to stop' \
          -e 'tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Picking a folder failed, exiting." with title "Start Up Error" buttons {"Ok"} with icon kStopIcon default button "Ok"'
```

{A few other more-or-less pedantic adjustments have also been made: there's now an explicit line continuation (`\`*newline*), for ease of testing in a shell; and, the `buttons …` labeled parameter now directly specifies a list, instead of involving an implicit coercion.}

Comment: I haven't verified this solution myself, because I solved it long ago by just switching to the Note icon instead, and I don't have ready access to MacOS 10.12.  But, this explanation does address the issue of "terminology conflict", and where the stop conflict comes from, and how to work around it with a variable.  I will accept this answer based on this factors, because this question is so old.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a terminology clash with `System Events`. Use the `Finder` instead.

```
osascript -e 'activate application "Finder"'
          -e 'tell application "Finder" to display dialog "Picking a folder failed, exiting." with title "Start Up Error" buttons "Ok" with icon stop default button "Ok"'
```

Since the Finder is running permanently the `quit` line can be omitted.

Comment: I'll give that a try.